# Prioritize\speed up stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure with loops and what not inside and recursive calling of other stored procedure and recursive calling of the stored procedure itself. This stored procedure has a lot of business logic inside it and  I won't go into the detail of the actual code, I've already tweaked it as much as possible from a code point of view  and also realize that having too much business logic in the actual stored isn't a best practice.

A part from this I was wondering if there is something that can be done to tell SQL to prioritize this single stored procedure or in some way have it use more resources to be faster or make it faster from a system point of view in any way?

Thank you

-------------------UPDATE--------------------

OK so from server fault I got a straight no answer for there being a magical botton or tweek to boost a stored procedure performance.
I'll try and put the code here.
I've got a main stored procedure that is very fast and is slow in only in this portion (if I comment this portion performance goes from 30-40seconds to 1 second):

```
IF (@REBUILD<>'L')
    BEGIN
        SET @Cycle = 0
        INSERT #PosTable ([Pos]) SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFP_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (Deleted=0) AND (Pos_sup IS NULL)
        IF(@@ROWCOUNT>0) SET @Cycle=1
        WHILE (@Cycle=1) 
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @Pos=[Pos] FROM #PosTable WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL)
            SET @NRPOS=@NRPOS+1
            EXEC ORD_OFFC_C @UserID, @Offer, @POS, @REBUILD, 1
            UPDATE #PosTable SET [Processed]='X' WHERE [Pos]=@Pos
            IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Pos] FROM #PosTable WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL))) SET @Cycle = 0

        END
    END
```

And here is the ORD_OFFC_C stored procedure. This procedure in it's self is faste enough (about 1-2 seconds), but launching it about 100 times in the above cycle obviously makes the whole procedure slow.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ORD_OFFC_R]
                 @UserID INT,                -- Utente
                 @OFFER INT,               -- Codice Offerta
                 @Rebuild CHAR(1),         -- 'X'=Cancella precedenti e rigenera, 'L'=Light, skip di ORD_OFFC_C sulle posizioni; ' ' aggiunge cond. inesistenti
                 @NoResult BIT = 0
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET DATEFORMAT DMY
    SET DATEFIRST 1
    
    DECLARE @Error INT
    DECLARE @SQL_ERROR INT
    DECLARE @Message AS NVARCHAR(600)
    DECLARE @POS AS INT
    DECLARE @NRPOS AS INT
    DECLARE @RIS AS INT
    DECLARE @R_CON AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @R_CON_PREV AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @R_TIP AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @R_RIP AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @R_POS AS INT
    DECLARE @P_VAL AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @R_VAL AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @TOT_CON AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @R_QTB AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @R_UMB AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @R_CVA AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @NR_KBETR AS INT
    DECLARE @R_CVU AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @R_CUM AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @Y_COATING_METHOD AS NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @Y_FITTING_COLOUR AS NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @Y_FITTING_RAL_COLOUR AS NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @Y_FITTING_SPECIAL_COLOUR AS NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @VALIDITA AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @NEW_VALIDITA AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @TODAY AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @SYS_ROWCOUNT AS INT
    DECLARE @KunNr AS NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @OBJ_CON AS INT
    DECLARE @CRM_CON AS INT

    DECLARE @T_CON AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @T_TIP AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_CAL AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_VAL AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_GRP AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_GRP_C AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_REP AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_REL AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_SHW AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @T_RIP AS CHAR(1)

    DECLARE @VALORE AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @PREC_VAL AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @KBETR AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @KBETR_UMB AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @KONWA AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @KMEIN AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @KMEIN_UMB AS NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @SEQ AS NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @CHIAVE_SEQ AS NVARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @SCA AS INT
    DECLARE @PosRelevant AS INT
    DECLARE @RefValue AS DECIMAL(18,3)
    DECLARE @S_ERR AS INT
    DECLARE @T_SEQ AS INT
    DECLARE @MAX_SEQ_GRP AS INT
    DECLARE @REP AS CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @Cycle AS BIT
    DECLARE @Id AS INT
    DECLARE @Chk_Data AS CHAR(1)

    CREATE TABLE #Positions ( [Pos] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [Y_PROCESSO] CHAR(1) NOT NULL, [POS_TYP] CHAR(2) NOT NULL, [IsRelevant] BIT NOT NULL, [PosValue] DECIMAL(18,3) NOT NULL )
    CREATE TABLE #CondPos ( [Condizione] NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, [Pos] INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([Condizione], [Pos]) )
    CREATE TABLE #PosTable (
          [Pos]     INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , [Processed]   CHAR(1) NULL
    )
    CREATE TABLE #Cond_A (
          [Id]                  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
        , [Pos]                 INT NOT NULL
        , [Condizione]          NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        , [Tipologia]           CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Ripartizione]        CHAR(1) NULL
        , [QTB]                 DECIMAL(18,3) NULL
        , [UMB]                 NVARCHAR(5) NULL
        , [KBETR]               DECIMAL(18,3) NULL
        , [KBETR_UMB]           DECIMAL(18,3) NULL
        , [KMEIN_UMB]           NVARCHAR(5) NULL
        , [Processed]           CHAR(1) NULL
    )
    CREATE TABLE #Cond_B (
          [Id]                  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
        , [Condizione]          NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        , [Tipologia]           CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Calcolo]             CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Valori]              CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Gruppo]              CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Gruppo_Calcolo]      CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Replace]             CHAR(1) NULL
        , [ReplaceLogic]        CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Show_Rule]           CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Ripartizione]        CHAR(1) NULL
        , [Sequenza]            INT NULL
        , [Processed]           CHAR(1) NULL
    )
    
    SET @Error=0
    SET @SQL_ERROR=0
    SET @Chk_Data = 'N' -- Default "NON OK", poi seguono controlli di conformità
    SET @NRPOS=0
    SET @TODAY=dbo.GetDateISOFormat(GETDATE())
    SET @REBUILD=ISNULL(@REBUILD, ' ')

    SELECT @Error=[Error] FROM dbo.ChkCRMAuthorization(@UserID,'OFFER\DEAL',@Offer,NULL,'IO')
    IF @Error<>0 GOTO USCITA

    SELECT @KunNr=KunNr, @OBJ_CON=SAP_Object, @CRM_CON=CRM_Conditions FROM ORD_OFF__MD WHERE OFFERTA=@Offer

    -- A) Loop su ORD_OFFP_MD
    IF (@REBUILD<>'L')
    BEGIN
        SET @Cycle = 0
        INSERT #PosTable ([Pos]) SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFP_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (Deleted=0) AND (Pos_sup IS NULL)
        IF(@@ROWCOUNT>0) SET @Cycle=1
        WHILE (@Cycle=1) 
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @Pos=[Pos] FROM #PosTable WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL)
            SET @NRPOS=@NRPOS+1
            EXEC ORD_OFFC_C @UserID, @Offer, @POS, @REBUILD, 1
            UPDATE #PosTable SET [Processed]='X' WHERE [Pos]=@Pos
            IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Pos] FROM #PosTable WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL))) SET @Cycle = 0

        END
    END
    -- A) Fine del Loop su posizioni


    -- B) Loop su ORD_TCON per controllo condizioni con Ripartizione (da eseguire sia per inserimento di condizioni che per aggiornamento)
    SET @Cycle = 0
    INSERT #Cond_A ([Pos], [Condizione], [Tipologia], [Ripartizione], [QTB], [UMB], [KBETR], [KBETR_UMB], [KMEIN_UMB]) 
        SELECT    P.POS, T.CONDIZIONE, T.TIPOLOGIA, T.RIPARTIZIONE, P.QTB, P.UMB, C.KBETR, KBETR_UMB, KMEIN_UMB
            FROM ORD_TCON AS T 
                INNER JOIN ORD_OFFC_MD AS C ON (C.CONDIZIONE=T.CONDIZIONE)
                INNER JOIN ORD_OFFP_MD AS P ON (P.OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (P.POS=C.POS) 
                WHERE   (P.OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (P.Deleted=0) AND (C.REPLACED=' ') 
                    AND (T.ATTIVO=1) AND (T.CALCOLO='P') AND (T.RIPARTIZIONE<>' ') 
            ORDER BY T.GRUPPO, T.SEQUENZA, C.POS
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT>0) SET @Cycle=1
    WHILE (@Cycle=1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Id=[Id], @R_POS=[Pos], @R_CON=[Condizione], @R_TIP=[Tipologia], @R_RIP=[Ripartizione], @R_QTB=[QTB], @R_UMB=[UMB], @R_CVA=[KBETR], @R_CVU=[KBETR_UMB], @R_CUM=[KMEIN_UMB]
            FROM #Cond_A WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL) ORDER BY [Id]

        SET @RIS=0
        SET @R_VAL=0
        SET @P_VAL=0
        SET @TOT_CON=0

        IF(@R_CON_PREV<>@R_CON) UPDATE ORD_OFFC_MD SET VALORE=0 WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (CONDIZIONE=@R_CON)

        SET @R_CON_PREV = @R_CON

        IF (@R_RIP='V') -- RIPARTIZIONE PER VARICOLOR su tutto l'ordine basata su valore e splittata per colore
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Y_COATING_METHOD=VAL_MAN FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=@R_POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_COATING_METHOD')
            SELECT @Y_FITTING_COLOUR=VAL_MAN FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=@R_POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_COLOUR')
            SELECT @Y_FITTING_RAL_COLOUR=VAL_MAN FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=@R_POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_RAL_COLOUR')
            SELECT @Y_FITTING_SPECIAL_COLOUR=VAL_MAN FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=@R_POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_SPECIAL_COLOUR')
            SET @NR_KBETR=0

            SELECT @TOT_CON=SUM(VALORE) 
                FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C INNER JOIN ORD_OFFP_MD AS P ON (C.OFFERTA=P.OFFERTA) AND (C.POS=P.POS)
                WHERE (C.CONDIZIONE<>@R_CON) AND (P.Deleted=0) AND (C.REPLACED=' ') AND (C.OFFERTA=@Offer)
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_COATING_METHOD') AND (VAL_MAN=@Y_COATING_METHOD)))
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_COLOUR') AND (VAL_MAN=@Y_FITTING_COLOUR)))
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_RAL_COLOUR') AND (IsNull(VAL_MAN,'')=IsNull(@Y_FITTING_RAL_COLOUR,''))))
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_SPECIAL_COLOUR') AND (IsNull(VAL_MAN,'')=IsNull(@Y_FITTING_SPECIAL_COLOUR,''))))

            SELECT @SYS_ROWCOUNT=COUNT(*) 
                FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C INNER JOIN ORD_OFFP_MD AS P ON (C.OFFERTA=P.OFFERTA) AND (C.POS=P.POS)
                WHERE (C.CONDIZIONE=@R_CON) AND (P.Deleted=0) AND (C.REPLACED=' ') AND (C.OFFERTA=@Offer)
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_COATING_METHOD') AND (VAL_MAN=@Y_COATING_METHOD)))
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_COLOUR') AND (VAL_MAN=@Y_FITTING_COLOUR)))
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_RAL_COLOUR') AND (IsNull(VAL_MAN,'')=IsNull(@Y_FITTING_RAL_COLOUR,''))))
                    AND (C.POS IN (SELECT POS FROM ORD_OFFY_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=C.OFFERTA) AND (POS=C.POS) AND (CARATTERISTICA='Y_FITTING_SPECIAL_COLOUR') AND (IsNull(VAL_MAN,'')=IsNull(@Y_FITTING_SPECIAL_COLOUR,'')))) 
                GROUP BY KBETR
            SELECT @NR_KBETR=@@ROWCOUNT WHERE (@@ERROR=0)

            SELECT @P_VAL=SUM(VALORE) 
                FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C INNER JOIN ORD_OFFP_MD AS P ON (C.OFFERTA=P.OFFERTA) AND (C.POS=P.POS)
                WHERE (C.CONDIZIONE<>@R_CON) AND (P.Deleted=0) AND (C.REPLACED=' ') AND (C.OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (C.POS=@R_POS)

            IF (((@R_CVU IS NOT NULL) OR (@R_CUM IS NOT NULL) OR (@NR_KBETR<>1) OR (@TOT_CON<=0)) AND (@Error=0)) SET @Error=107

            IF (@TOT_CON>0) SET @R_VAL=@R_CVA*(@P_VAL/@TOT_CON) ELSE SET @R_VAL=0
            SET @RIS=1
        END

        IF (@RIS=1) AND (@Error=0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ORD_OFFC_MD SET VALORE=@R_VAL WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=@R_POS) AND (CONDIZIONE=@R_CON)
        END ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ORD_OFFP_MD SET CHECK_PRICING='X' WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=@R_POS)
        END

        UPDATE #Cond_A SET [Processed]='X' WHERE [Id]=@Id
        IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Id] FROM #Cond_A WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL))) SET @Cycle = 0
        
    END
    -- B) Fine del Loop per Ripartizioni

    -- C.1) Step di determinazione condizioni di testata per la determinazione sulle posizioni
    --      2021/02/04 GA Introduzione sconti di testata ZI11 e ZI12
    IF (@REBUILD='X') 
    BEGIN
        DELETE ORD_OFFC_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=0)
    END ELSE
    BEGIN
        DELETE ORD_OFFC_MD WHERE (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=0) AND (TIPOLOGIA='A')
    END

    DELETE ORD_OFFC_MD 
        FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C
        INNER JOIN ORD_TCON AS T ON (C.Condizione=T.Condizione)
        WHERE (C.OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS>0) AND (T.CALCOLO='T')

    INSERT #Positions ([Pos], [Y_PROCESSO], [POS_TYP], [IsRelevant], [PosValue])
        SELECT    P.[Pos] AS [Pos]
                , ISNULL(Y.[Val_man], '0') AS [Y_PROCESSO]
                , ISNULL(P.[POS_TYP], '') AS [POS_TYP]
                , 0 AS [IsRelevant]
                , ISNULL(C.[PosValue], 0) AS [PosValue]
            FROM ORD_OFFP_MD AS P
                LEFT JOIN ORD_OFFY_MD AS Y ON (P.[Offerta]=Y.[Offerta]) AND (P.[Pos]=Y.[Pos]) AND (Y.Caratteristica='Y_PROCESSO')
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Offerta], [Pos], SUM([VALORE]) AS [PosValue] FROM ORD_OFFC_MD WHERE (REPLACED='') AND (Show IN ('S', 'V')) GROUP BY [Offerta], [Pos]) AS C ON (P.[Offerta]=C.[Offerta]) AND (P.[Pos]=C.[Pos])
            WHERE (P.[Offerta]=@Offer) AND (P.[Deleted]=0)


    SET @Cycle = 0
    INSERT #Cond_B ( [Condizione], [Tipologia], [Calcolo], [Valori], [Gruppo], [Gruppo_Calcolo], [Replace], [Show_Rule], [Ripartizione] ) 
        SELECT CONDIZIONE, TIPOLOGIA, CALCOLO, VALORI, GRUPPO, GRUPPO_CALCOLO, [REPLACE], SHOW_RULE, RIPARTIZIONE 
            FROM ORD_TCON 
            WHERE (ATTIVO=1) AND (CALCOLO = 'T') 
            ORDER BY GRUPPO, SEQUENZA
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT>0) SET @Cycle=1
    WHILE (@Cycle=1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Id=[Id], @T_CON=[Condizione], @T_TIP=[Tipologia], @T_CAL=[Calcolo], @T_VAL=[Valori], @T_GRP=[Gruppo], @T_GRP_C=[Gruppo_Calcolo], @T_REP=[Replace], @T_SHW=[Show_Rule], @T_RIP=[Ripartizione]
            FROM #Cond_B WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL) ORDER BY [Id]

        SET @VALORE=NULL
        SET @PREC_VAL=NULL
        SET @KBETR=NULL
        SET @KONWA=NULL
        SET @KMEIN=NULL
        SET @KBETR_UMB=NULL
        SET @KMEIN_UMB=NULL
        SET @RIS=0
        SET @S_ERR=NULL
        SET @SEQ=NULL
        SET @SCA=NULL
        SET @PosRelevant=0
        SET @Chiave_SEQ=NULL

        IF(@T_CON IN ('ZI11', 'ZI12')) -- Gestire i controllo di rilevanza per posizioni in base alla condizione (in SAP sono i presupposti)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE P SET [IsRelevant] = CASE WHEN ((T.Condizione IS NOT NULL) AND (P.[POS_TYP]<>'B1')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            FROM #Positions AS P
                LEFT JOIN ORD_TCOV AS T ON (T.Condizione=@T_CON) AND (T.Processo=P.Y_PROCESSO)
        END ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #Positions SET [IsRelevant] = 0
        END

        -- Preparo tabella per popolamento condizioni a livello di riga
        INSERT #CondPos ([Condizione], [Pos]) SELECT @T_CON, [Pos] FROM #Positions WHERE [IsRelevant]=1 

        SELECT @PosRelevant = COUNT(*), @RefValue = SUM([PosValue]) FROM #Positions WHERE ([IsRelevant]=1)

        IF ((NOT EXISTS(SELECT CONDIZIONE FROM ORD_OFFC_MD WHERE OFFERTA=@Offer AND POS=0 AND CONDIZIONE=@T_CON)) AND (@PosRelevant>0))
        BEGIN -- Se non esistono condizioni Manuali, verifico determinaizone di condizioni automatiche

            IF(@T_CON='ZI11')
            BEGIN
                SELECT @S_ERR=ERROR, @KBETR=KBETR, @KONWA=KONWA, @KMEIN=KMEIN, @KBETR_UMB=KBETR, @KMEIN_UMB=KMEIN, @SEQ=SEQUENZA, @Chiave_SEQ=Chiave_Sequenza, @SCA=SCAGLIONE 
                        FROM dbo.GET_ZI11(@UserID, @KunNr, @OBJ_CON, @CRM_CON, 0, @RefValue)
                IF @S_ERR=0 SET @RIS=1
            END
            IF(@T_CON='ZI12')
            BEGIN
                SELECT @S_ERR=ERROR, @KBETR=KBETR, @KONWA=KONWA, @KMEIN=KMEIN, @KBETR_UMB=KBETR, @KMEIN_UMB=KMEIN, @SEQ=SEQUENZA, @Chiave_SEQ=Chiave_Sequenza, @SCA=SCAGLIONE 
                        FROM dbo.GET_ZI12(@UserID, @KunNr, @OBJ_CON, @CRM_CON, 0, @RefValue)
                IF @S_ERR=0 SET @RIS=1
            END

            IF (@RIS=1) 
            BEGIN
                IF (@KONWA='%') SET @VALORE=@RefValue*@KBETR/100

                INSERT ORD_OFFC_MD (OFFERTA, POS, CONDIZIONE, VALORE, KBETR, KONWA, KMEIN, KBETR_UMB, KMEIN_UMB, GRUPPO, REPLACED, SHOW, SEQUENZA, Chiave_Sequenza, SCAGLIONE, TIPOLOGIA, USERID_UPD, DATA_UPD)
                        VALUES (@Offer, 0, @T_CON, @VALORE, @KBETR, @KONWA, @KMEIN, @KBETR_UMB, @KMEIN_UMB, @T_GRP, ' ', @T_SHW, @SEQ, @CHIAVE_SEQ, @SCA, 'A', @UserID, GETDATE() )

            END
        END ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Ricalcolo il valore della condizione manuale inserita
            UPDATE ORD_OFFC_MD SET VALORE=@RefValue*KBETR/100
                WHERE OFFERTA=@Offer AND POS=0 AND CONDIZIONE=@T_CON AND KONWA='%'

        END

        UPDATE #Cond_B SET [Processed]='X' WHERE [Id]=@Id
        IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Id] FROM #Cond_B WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL))) SET @Cycle = 0

    END
    -- C.1) Fine Step

    -- C.2) Controllo Condizioni di testata: Replacement
    DELETE #Cond_B
    SET @Cycle = 0
    INSERT #Cond_B ( [Condizione], [Tipologia], [Calcolo], [Valori], [Gruppo], [Gruppo_Calcolo], [Replace], [ReplaceLogic], [Show_Rule], [Ripartizione], [Sequenza] ) 
        SELECT T.CONDIZIONE, T.TIPOLOGIA, T.CALCOLO, T.VALORI, T.GRUPPO, T.GRUPPO_CALCOLO, T.[REPLACE], T.[REPLACELOGIC], T.SHOW_RULE, T.RIPARTIZIONE, T.SEQUENZA 
            FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C INNER JOIN ORD_TCON AS T ON (C.CONDIZIONE=T.CONDIZIONE)
            WHERE   (C.OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=0)
                AND (T.ATTIVO=1) AND (T.CALCOLO='T')
            ORDER BY T.GRUPPO, T.SEQUENZA
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT>0) SET @Cycle=1
    WHILE (@Cycle=1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Id=[Id], @T_CON=[Condizione], @T_TIP=[Tipologia], @T_CAL=[Calcolo], @T_VAL=[Valori], @T_GRP=[Gruppo], @T_GRP_C=[Gruppo_Calcolo], @T_REP=[Replace], @T_REL=[ReplaceLogic], @T_SHW=[Show_Rule], @T_RIP=[Ripartizione], @T_SEQ=[Sequenza]
            FROM #Cond_B WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL) ORDER BY [Id]
        /*
            Replace G : sostituisce qualsiasi condizione dello stesso gruppo di calcolo lasciando solo l'ultima in ordine di sequenza
            Replace S : sostituisce le condizioni di VALORE=S dello stesso gruppo di calcolo lasciando solo l'ultima in ordine di sequenza
            Replcae Q : sostituisce qualsiasi condizione dello stesso gruppo di calcolo lasciando solo l'ultima in ordine di sequenza che abbia REPLACELOGIC=MgmtType (solo per posizioni)
        */
        SET @REP=' '
        SET @MAX_SEQ_GRP=0

        SELECT @MAX_SEQ_GRP=MAX(T.SEQUENZA) FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C INNER JOIN ORD_TCON AS T ON (C.CONDIZIONE=T.CONDIZIONE)
            WHERE   (C.OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=0) AND (T.ATTIVO=1) AND (T.CALCOLO='T') AND (T.GRUPPO=@T_GRP)

        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT C.CONDIZIONE FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C INNER JOIN ORD_TCON AS T ON (C.CONDIZIONE=T.CONDIZIONE) 
                        WHERE   (C.OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (C.POS=0) 
                            AND (T.GRUPPO_CALCOLO=@T_GRP) AND ([REPLACE]='G') ))
        BEGIN
            IF (@T_SEQ<@MAX_SEQ_GRP) SET @REP='X'
        END
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        IF (EXISTS(SELECT C.CONDIZIONE FROM ORD_OFFC_MD AS C INNER JOIN ORD_TCON AS T ON (C.CONDIZIONE=T.CONDIZIONE) 
                        WHERE   (C.OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (C.POS=0) 
                            AND (T.GRUPPO_CALCOLO=@T_GRP) AND ([REPLACE]='S') ))
        BEGIN
            IF (@T_SEQ<@MAX_SEQ_GRP) AND (@T_VAL='S') SET @REP='X'                  
        END
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        UPDATE ORD_OFFC_MD SET REPLACED=@REP 
            WHERE   (OFFERTA=@Offer) AND (POS=0) 
                AND (CONDIZIONE=@T_CON) AND (GRUPPO=@T_GRP)

        UPDATE #Cond_B SET [Processed]='X' WHERE [Id]=@Id
        IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Id] FROM #Cond_B WHERE ([Processed] IS NULL))) SET @Cycle = 0

    END
    -- C.2) Fine Step

    -- C.3) Inserimento condizioni di testata a livello di riga (per informazione statistica puntuale)
    INSERT ORD_OFFC_MD (OFFERTA, POS, CONDIZIONE
                      , VALORE, KBETR, KONWA, KMEIN, KBETR_UMB, KMEIN_UMB, GRUPPO, REPLACED, SHOW, SEQUENZA,Chiave_Sequenza, SCAGLIONE, TIPOLOGIA, USERID_UPD, DATA_UPD)
            SELECT      @Offer, C.[Pos], C.[Condizione]
                      , P.[PosValue]*H.KBETR/100 AS [VALORE] 
                      , H.KBETR, H.KONWA, H.KMEIN, H.KBETR_UMB, H.KMEIN_UMB, H.GRUPPO, H.REPLACED, H.SHOW, H.SEQUENZA, H.Chiave_Sequenza, H.SCAGLIONE, 'A', H.USERID_UPD, H.DATA_UPD
                FROM #CondPos AS C
                    INNER JOIN ORD_TCON AS T ON (C.Condizione=T.Condizione) AND (T.CALCOLO='T')
                    INNER JOIN ORD_OFFC_MD AS H ON (H.[Offerta]=@Offer) AND (H.[Pos]=0) AND (H.[Condizione]=C.[Condizione]) AND (H.[Replaced]='')
                    INNER JOIN #Positions AS P ON (C.[Pos]=P.[Pos])
                WHERE (H.KONWA='%')

    -- C.3) Fine Step

    IF (@Error=0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @VALIDITA=VALIDITA FROM ORD_OFF__MD WHERE OFFERTA=@Offer
        IF @VALIDITA<@TODAY SET @NEW_VALIDITA=@TODAY
        IF (@NEW_VALIDITA IS NOT NULL) UPDATE ORD_OFF__MD SET VALIDITA=@NEW_VALIDITA WHERE OFFERTA=@Offer
        UPDATE ORD_OFF__MD SET DATA_PREZZO=@TODAY, Chk_CRM_Cond=' ' WHERE OFFERTA=@Offer
    END

USCITA:
  SELECT @CHK_DATA=CHK_DATA FROM dbo.ChkOfferData(@UserID, @Offer)
  UPDATE ORD_OFF__MD SET [Chk_Data] = @Chk_Data WHERE OFFERTA = @Offer
  SET @SQL_ERROR=@@ERROR
  IF (@SQL_ERROR<>0) AND (@Error=0) SET @Error=117

  IF (@Error=0) EXEC ORD_OFF_INDEX @UserID, @Offer, 'R', 1, @Error OUT, @Message OUT

  IF (@Error<>0) 
  BEGIN 
    SET @Message=dbo.GetText(@UserID, NULL, 'ERROR', @Error, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
  END
  IF (@NoResult=0) SELECT @Error AS ERRORE, @Message AS MESSAGGIO, @NRPOS AS NR_POS
```

All other procedure called in ORD_OFFC_C are very fast, I can provide individual code if needed.

Comment: *"with loops"* That there is your problem.

Comment: Yeah I know, I changed the cursors using a temp table and then a while(exists(...)) ecc but it hardly made any difference.

Comment: Changing to cursors isn't going to help; you need to move to set based operations. Of course, what you need to do to do that is impossible for us to say; you've given us no code to help you with.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for performance tuning help, but includes no SQL or examples. The solution is likely to change from a iterative solution to a set based one, however, it is impossible for the users here to explain how that would be achieved without the existing solution(s).

Comment: [RBAR: ‘Row By Agonizing Row’](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/)

Comment: @Larnu is there somewhere I can paste code to and link it in the question?

Comment: @James yes, the question. [Edit] the question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it wouldn't fit I'd need a lot more space. I'll try server fault, didn't connect that this area is only for code problems.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning can I get a reopen vote?

Comment: You might find https://dba.stackexchange.com/ more suited to this question.